# In a Jenkins Pipeline script, how do I assign a path with a space to an environment variable?

Tags: jenkins

I'm assigning a path with a space in it to an environment variable using the following syntax:

```
environment {
   ZIP_HOME = "C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip"
}
```

I'm trying to use 7-Zip to zip my files and using the variable as the path to the 7-Zip executable.

```
bat "%ZIP_HOME%\\7z a programdata-${BUILD_NUMBER}.zip ${WORKSPACE}/Staging/programdata"
```

I also tried putting braces around ZIP_HOME.

```
bat "${ZIP_HOME}\\7z.exe a programdata-${BUILD_NUMBER}.zip ${WORKSPACE}/Staging/programdata"
```

I get the following message in the console output:

```
   'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

I also tried putting single quotes around 'Program Files' within the path above but get the same message.

The syntax I used for the bat "{ZIP_HOME}\7z is an answer I found on this site but it didn't work for me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I found the following syntax in another question but I'm getting the same message:

bat "${ZIP_HOME}7z a myZipFile.zip srcFolder"

Comment: I have the solution. I used %ProgramFiles% instead but the true fix was to add escaped quotes around the path to the 7z executable as follows:

bat "\"%ProgramFiles%\\7-Zip\"\\7z a NameofZipFile.zip ${WORKSPACE}/StagingFolder"

Comment: Care to juat delete your Q as you figured it out and it's answered elsewhere here, so not adding to the body of knowledge.